# Get domain origin IP address when it uses a CDN

Tags: c#, .net-core, dns, cdn

I have a project that is gathering server information for specified domains. It is important that I am getting details of the origin host server. I am using the following to get an IP address:

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(domain);
```

and then everything else I can get from that IP address. The problem I have is that while this works fine for a domain that is not using a CDN, anything that does is not returning the origin server's IP address, but the IP address of the nearest edge server. What can I use instead to make sure I'm always getting the origin server?

Comment: CDN returns the data stored in some storage and uses cache and edge locations to return them faster... The storage can be a cloud storage... Do you need the IP for the exact server on which the data is stored?

Comment: Yes, I need the IP for the origin server that all the CDN edge/cache servers will retrieve the data from.

Comment: That's not possible I believe... why do you need to know the IP of the origin server?

Comment: I am performing analysis that is dependent on it's geo-location

Comment: as you mentioned, CDN IPs are from the nearest edge location... so that will give you more accurate information about geo-location.. the origin server can be located anywhere... for example.. AWS storage bucket can be located in US-East region but accessing CDN from Singapore will give you the nearest IP of CDN from Singapore... also the storage of cloud service are another level of abstraction which never reveals the target storage location details...

Comment: Yes but it is not the geo location of the edge that I need to analyse, but the location of the origin.

Comment: Well, CDN location *is* the origin from your client's point of view (in a kind of "meta" sense :), but also practically - most of the time content will be served from CDN. It should be easy to accept that because that is all you have :)